# Why is <$> slow?

Tags: haskell

I was performing a bit of cleanup on my code recently, and in the process changed this (not quite the real code):

```
read = act readSTRef
test1 term i var = do
    t <- fromRTerm term
    v <- rep var 
    ty <- v^!varType.read
    ts <- v^!terms.read
    let ts' = TL.toVector ts
    when (ty /= Void && V.length ts' == 1) . updateChild term t i $ ts' V.! 0
    V.mapM_ substitute ts'
```

to this:

```
read = act readSTRef
test2 term i var = do
    t <- fromRTerm term
    v <- rep var
    ty <- v^!varType.read
    ts <- TL.toVector <$> v^!terms.read
    when (ty /= Void && V.length ts == 1) . updateChild term t i $ ts V.! 0
    V.mapM_ substitute ts
```

Obviously, these are semantically identical. However, the later runs significantly slower (I tested with only changing those lines to ensure that was the actual cause). Looking at the dumped core, I can't identify any obvious differences, and `<$>` appears to be inlined in both. Why can't GHC optimise the latter to the former?

I should note that there are multiple places in my program that could be written either way, and the performance impact of `<$>` is consistent between them (about half a second per ).

I've removed the core for the tests, since it was clear that they were identical. So, here is the core for the actual function.

First way:

```
case ipv5_X2Q6 of _ [Occ=Dead] {
  __DEFAULT ->
    case GHC.Prim.writeMutVar#
           @ s_aJBu
           @ TypeInferencer.Stage
           dt5_dMoe
           TypeInferencer.Substituted
           ipv4_X2Q4
    of s2#_aP5h { __DEFAULT ->
    letrec {
      a15_sSPP [Occ=LoopBreaker]
        :: [GHC.Types.Int]
           -> [TypeInferencer.RNode s_aJBu]
           -> GHC.Prim.State# s_aJBu
           -> (# GHC.Prim.State# s_aJBu, () #)
      [LclId, Arity=3, Str=DmdType <S,1*U><L,1*U><L,U>]
      a15_sSPP =
        \ (ds_aPlu :: [GHC.Types.Int])
          (_ys_aPlv :: [TypeInferencer.RNode s_aJBu])
          (eta_B1 :: GHC.Prim.State# s_aJBu) ->
          case ds_aPlu of _ [Occ=Dead] {
            [] -> (# eta_B1, GHC.Tuple.() #);
            : ipv6_aPlA ipv7_aPlB ->
              case _ys_aPlv of _ [Occ=Dead] {
                [] -> (# eta_B1, GHC.Tuple.() #);
                : ipv8_aPlH ipv9_aPlI ->
                  tick<substitute.go>
                  case scc<substitute.go>
                       (scctick<fromRNode>
                        GHC.STRef.readSTRef1
                          @ s_aJBu
                          @ (Data.Either.Either
                               (TypeInferencer.Term s_aJBu) (TypeInferencer.Var s_aJBu))
                          (ipv8_aPlH
                           `cast` (TypeInferencer.NTCo:RNode[0] <s_aJBu>_N
                                   :: TypeInferencer.RNode s_aJBu
                                        ~#
                                      GHC.STRef.STRef
                                        s_aJBu
                                        (Data.Either.Either
                                           (TypeInferencer.Term s_aJBu)
                                           (TypeInferencer.Var s_aJBu)))))
                         eta_B1
                  of _ [Occ=Dead] { (# ipv10_X2DV, ipv11_X2DX #) ->
                  case ipv11_X2DX of _ [Occ=Dead] {
                    Data.Either.Left ds5_dLX6 ->
                      case scc<substitute.go> a11_rYpY @ s_aJBu ipv8_aPlH ipv10_X2DV
                      of _ [Occ=Dead] { (# ipv12_a2tf, ipv13_a2tg #) ->
                      a15_sSPP ipv7_aPlB ipv9_aPlI ipv12_a2tf
                      };
                    Data.Either.Right var_aJrt ->
                      case scc<substitute.go> a14_sPTG ipv10_X2DV
                      of _ [Occ=Dead] { (# ipv12_X2PP, ipv13_X2PR #) ->
                      tick<rep>
                      case scc<substitute.go>
                           scc<rep> a4_rYnT @ s_aJBu var_aJrt ipv12_X2PP
                      of _ [Occ=Dead] { (# ipv14_X2PW, ipv15_X2PY #) ->
                      case scc<substitute.go>
                           scc<rep> a3_rYnR @ s_aJBu ipv15_X2PY var_aJrt ipv14_X2PW
                      of _ [Occ=Dead] { (# ipv16_X2Q0, ipv17_X2Q2 #) ->
                      case ipv17_X2Q2
                      of _ [Occ=Dead]
                      { TypeInferencer.Var dt6_dMth x1_XJka dt7_dMti dt8_dMtj dt9_dMtk
                                           dt10_dMtl dt11_dMtm ->
                      case scc<substitute.go>
                           GHC.Prim.readMutVar#
                             @ s_aJBu @ TypeInferencer.VarType dt7_dMti ipv16_X2Q0
                      of _ [Occ=Dead] { (# ipv18_X2Qt, ipv19_X2Qv #) ->
                      case scc<substitute.go>
                           GHC.Prim.readMutVar#
                             @ s_aJBu
                             @ (TreeList.TreeList (TypeInferencer.RNode s_aJBu))
                             dt9_dMtk
                             ipv18_X2Qt
                      of _ [Occ=Dead] { (# ipv20_X2QL, ipv21_X2QN #) ->
                      case scc<substitute.go>
                           scctick<substitute.go.ts'>
                           TreeList.toVector @ (TypeInferencer.RNode s_aJBu) ipv21_X2QN
                      of _ [Occ=Dead] { Data.Vector.Vector ww1_sTzM ww2_sTzN ww3_sTzO ->
                      tick<==>
                      tick</=>
                      case scc<substitute.go>
                           let {
                             $w$j_sTA0
                               :: GHC.Prim.State# s_aJBu -> (# GHC.Prim.State# s_aJBu, () #)
                             [LclId, Arity=1, Str=DmdType <L,U>]
                             $w$j_sTA0 =
                               \ (w_sTzY :: GHC.Prim.State# s_aJBu) ->
                                 letrec {
                                   $s$wa_sWUL [Occ=LoopBreaker]
                                     :: GHC.Prim.Int#
                                        -> GHC.Prim.State# s_aJBu
                                        -> (# GHC.Prim.State# s_aJBu, () #)
                                   [LclId, Arity=2, Str=DmdType <L,U><L,U>]
                                   $s$wa_sWUL =
                                     \ (sc_sWUJ :: GHC.Prim.Int#)
                                       (sc1_sWUK :: GHC.Prim.State# s_aJBu) ->
                                       case GHC.Prim.tagToEnum#
                                              @ GHC.Types.Bool (GHC.Prim.>=# sc_sWUJ ww2_sTzN)
                                       of _ [Occ=Dead] {
                                         GHC.Types.False ->
                                           case GHC.Prim.indexArray#
                                                  @ (TypeInferencer.RNode s_aJBu)
                                                  ww3_sTzO
                                                  (GHC.Prim.+# ww1_sTzM sc_sWUJ)
                                           of _ [Occ=Dead] { (# ipv22_aQSr #) ->
                                           case a11_rYpY @ s_aJBu ipv22_aQSr sc1_sWUK
                                           of _ [Occ=Dead] { (# ipv23_X2EL, ipv24_X2EN #) ->
                                           $s$wa_sWUL (GHC.Prim.+# sc_sWUJ 1) ipv23_X2EL
                                           }
                                           };
                                         GHC.Types.True -> (# sc1_sWUK, GHC.Tuple.() #)
                                       }; } in
                                 $s$wa_sWUL 0 w_sTzY } in
```

Second way:

```
case ipv5_X2Q6 of _ [Occ=Dead] {
  __DEFAULT ->
    case GHC.Prim.writeMutVar#
           @ s_aJBt
           @ TypeInferencer.Stage
           dt5_dMog
           TypeInferencer.Substituted
           ipv4_X2Q4
    of s2#_aP5h { __DEFAULT ->
    letrec {
      a15_sSPP [Occ=LoopBreaker]
        :: [GHC.Types.Int]
           -> [TypeInferencer.RNode s_aJBt]
           -> GHC.Prim.State# s_aJBt
           -> (# GHC.Prim.State# s_aJBt, () #)
      [LclId, Arity=3, Str=DmdType <S,1*U><L,1*U><L,U>]
      a15_sSPP =
        \ (ds_aPlu :: [GHC.Types.Int])
          (_ys_aPlv :: [TypeInferencer.RNode s_aJBt])
          (eta_B1 :: GHC.Prim.State# s_aJBt) ->
          case ds_aPlu of _ [Occ=Dead] {
            [] -> (# eta_B1, GHC.Tuple.() #);
            : ipv6_aPlA ipv7_aPlB ->
              case _ys_aPlv of _ [Occ=Dead] {
                [] -> (# eta_B1, GHC.Tuple.() #);
                : ipv8_aPlH ipv9_aPlI ->
                  tick<substitute.go>
                  case scc<substitute.go>
                       (scctick<fromRNode>
                        GHC.STRef.readSTRef1
                          @ s_aJBt
                          @ (Data.Either.Either
                               (TypeInferencer.Term s_aJBt) (TypeInferencer.Var s_aJBt))
                          (ipv8_aPlH
                           `cast` (TypeInferencer.NTCo:RNode[0] <s_aJBt>_N
                                   :: TypeInferencer.RNode s_aJBt
                                        ~#
                                      GHC.STRef.STRef
                                        s_aJBt
                                        (Data.Either.Either
                                           (TypeInferencer.Term s_aJBt)
                                           (TypeInferencer.Var s_aJBt)))))
                         eta_B1
                  of _ [Occ=Dead] { (# ipv10_X2DV, ipv11_X2DX #) ->
                  case ipv11_X2DX of _ [Occ=Dead] {
                    Data.Either.Left ds5_dLX8 ->
                      case scc<substitute.go> a11_rYpY @ s_aJBt ipv8_aPlH ipv10_X2DV
                      of _ [Occ=Dead] { (# ipv12_a2tf, ipv13_a2tg #) ->
                      a15_sSPP ipv7_aPlB ipv9_aPlI ipv12_a2tf
                      };
                    Data.Either.Right var_aJrt ->
                      case scc<substitute.go> a14_sPTG ipv10_X2DV
                      of _ [Occ=Dead] { (# ipv12_X2PP, ipv13_X2PR #) ->
                      tick<rep>
                      case scc<substitute.go>
                           scc<rep> a4_rYnT @ s_aJBt var_aJrt ipv12_X2PP
                      of _ [Occ=Dead] { (# ipv14_X2PW, ipv15_X2PY #) ->
                      case scc<substitute.go>
                           scc<rep> a3_rYnR @ s_aJBt ipv15_X2PY var_aJrt ipv14_X2PW
                      of _ [Occ=Dead] { (# ipv16_X2Q0, ipv17_X2Q2 #) ->
                      case ipv17_X2Q2
                      of _ [Occ=Dead]
                      { TypeInferencer.Var dt6_dMtj x1_XJka dt7_dMtk dt8_dMtl dt9_dMtm
                                           dt10_dMtn dt11_dMto ->
                      case scc<substitute.go>
                           GHC.Prim.readMutVar#
                             @ s_aJBt @ TypeInferencer.VarType dt7_dMtk ipv16_X2Q0
                      of _ [Occ=Dead] { (# ipv18_X2Qt, ipv19_X2Qv #) ->
                      case scc<substitute.go>
                           GHC.Prim.readMutVar#
                             @ s_aJBt
                             @ (TreeList.TreeList (TypeInferencer.RNode s_aJBt))
                             dt9_dMtm
                             ipv18_X2Qt
                      of _ [Occ=Dead] { (# ipv20_a6bS, ipv21_a6bT #) ->
                      case scc<substitute.go>
                           TreeList.toVector @ (TypeInferencer.RNode s_aJBt) ipv21_a6bT
                      of _ [Occ=Dead] { Data.Vector.Vector ww1_sTzM ww2_sTzN ww3_sTzO ->
                      tick<==>
                      tick</=>
                      case scc<substitute.go>
                           let {
                             $w$j_sTA0
                               :: GHC.Prim.State# s_aJBt -> (# GHC.Prim.State# s_aJBt, () #)
                             [LclId, Arity=1, Str=DmdType <L,U>]
                             $w$j_sTA0 =
                               \ (w_sTzY :: GHC.Prim.State# s_aJBt) ->
                                 letrec {
                                   $s$wa_sWUL [Occ=LoopBreaker]
                                     :: GHC.Prim.Int#
                                        -> GHC.Prim.State# s_aJBt
                                        -> (# GHC.Prim.State# s_aJBt, () #)
                                   [LclId, Arity=2, Str=DmdType <L,U><L,U>]
                                   $s$wa_sWUL =
                                     \ (sc_sWUJ :: GHC.Prim.Int#)
                                       (sc1_sWUK :: GHC.Prim.State# s_aJBt) ->
                                       case GHC.Prim.tagToEnum#
                                              @ GHC.Types.Bool (GHC.Prim.>=# sc_sWUJ ww2_sTzN)
                                       of _ [Occ=Dead] {
                                         GHC.Types.False ->
                                           case GHC.Prim.indexArray#
                                                  @ (TypeInferencer.RNode s_aJBt)
                                                  ww3_sTzO
                                                  (GHC.Prim.+# ww1_sTzM sc_sWUJ)
                                           of _ [Occ=Dead] { (# ipv22_aQSr #) ->
                                           case a11_rYpY @ s_aJBt ipv22_aQSr sc1_sWUK
                                           of _ [Occ=Dead] { (# ipv23_X2EL, ipv24_X2EN #) ->
                                           $s$wa_sWUL (GHC.Prim.+# sc_sWUJ 1) ipv23_X2EL
                                           }
                                           };
                                         GHC.Types.True -> (# sc1_sWUK, GHC.Tuple.() #)
                                       }; } in
                                 $s$wa_sWUL 0 w_sTzY } in
```

Comment: Can you post the "Core", i.e. run `ghc -O2 -ddump-simpl <filename>` on both functions?

Comment: Thanks for posting the Core. I might be a bit blind but except for identifier names the two piece of Core generated look equal to me. So my first guess would be that you performd your timings without compiling with -O2, or there's some flakyness in your measurements (system load? differing input data? something else?).

Comment: I've added it, but they appear identical. I think I oversimplified the example. I'll try and come up with a better one.

Comment: @klkblake: Could you please post the core with annotations? If they are also the same, you really have oversimplified the example.

Comment: Looks like the only difference is a scctick in the faster one, but that makes no sense.

Comment: Did you check the timings with optimizations enabled?

Comment: Just a wild guess, but maybe it's related to stream fusion? In the first example, it's easier for GHC to see that ts' is constructed using toVector, while in the second example, GHC would have to inline bind to see that.

Comment: Optimisations were enabled, yes. I also found that when the program was built without profiling enabled, they ran exactly the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose to answer this question for posterity -- "when the program was built without profiling enabled, they ran exactly the same". This makes perfect sense as additional function calls that are inlined away nonetheless, when profiling is enabled, must leave some trace for a cost center.

Heisenberg's principle in action -- if we observe our program too closely, we end up changing it!